# Pyspark matching version with Scala for Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm running into issues with pyspark on structured streaming..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-streaming-project/streaming/data_stream.py", line 31, in <module>
    run_spark_job(spark)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-streaming-project/streaming/data_stream.py", line 11, in run_spark_job
    .option("subscribe", "service-calls") \
  File "/Users/dev/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 403, in load
  File "/Users/dev/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/Users/dev/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/Users/dev/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 23 more
```

I'm using python version 3.6.8, spark version 2.4.3, scala version 2.11.8, and java version 1.8.
The command I used was

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.3 data_stream.py
```

within the directory where data_stream.py exists.

Seems like it's just a version issue but I've read through few threads and mine still throws errors like this.. please help!

Comment: Have you tried `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3` instead of `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.3`? because you are using Scala 2.11 and not 2.12

Comment: ahh Thank you so much for this! I wish they had a better documentation for version config to run these things.