# Scala version inside PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, java-11

PySpark uses Java or OpenJDK to run. Does it also use Scala somewhere? If yes, then how to find out it's version?

The PySpark-shell shows the following:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '67424e82' at 'null' in 'null'
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'Default' at 'null' in 'null'
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/21 03:11:12 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.4.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023 11:10:38)
Spark context Web UI available at http://0a101be597b1:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1689909072697).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> sc.version
'3.4.1'
>>> spark.version
'3.4.1'
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345685/pyspark-matching-version-with-scala-for-structured-streaming) shows that Scala is being used in PySpark but again, nothing about Scala version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
spark.sparkContext._gateway.jvm.scala.util.Properties.versionString()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).